# Django.db.utils.DatabaseError with MongoDB as Backend Database

Tags: django, database, mongodb, djongo

```
Internal Server Error: /loginapi/registeruser/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 929, in _insert
    query.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 397, in execute
    res = self.db[self.left_table].insert_many(docs, ordered=False)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 770, in insert_many
    blk.execute(write_concern, session=session)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 533, in execute
    return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern, session)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 366, in execute_command
    _raise_bulk_write_error(full_result)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 140, in _raise_bulk_write_error
    raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred, full error: {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: PP1.loginapi_user index: email_1 dup key: { email: "m@gmail.com" }', 'keyPattern': {'email': 1}, 'keyValue': {'email': 'm@gmail.com'}, 'op': {'id': 18, 'last_login': None, 'is_superuser': False, 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'is_staff': False, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 8, 7, 7, 44, 901495), 'name': 'g', 'email': 'm@gmail.com', 'password': '', '_id': ObjectId('636a0040d416e6cc888d66d5')}}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 869, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "loginapi_user" ("last_login", "is_superuser", "first_name", "last_name", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined", "name", "email", "password") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s, %(5)s, %(6)s, %(7)s, %(8)s, %(9)s)
        Params: [None, False, '', '', False, True, datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 8, 7, 7, 44, 901495), 'g', 'm@gmail.com', '']
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Connect\connect_django\loginapi\views.py", line 14, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "E:\Connect\connect_django\loginapi\serializers.py", line 18, in create
    return super().create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 514, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 68, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1434, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1621, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

How do I fix the Django Database error? I'm using MongoDB with Djongo.

Everything was working fine until recently when I decided to add NewApp. Whenever I try to migrate, it got migrated, but when I send a POST request to this URL, it shows me this error.

I tried deleting the migration files and  folder also but had no luck
I tried resetting the Database Manually as well as from the Terminal but had no luck.

I think it's super simple but I am new to Django and MongoDB and can't seem to figure out how to fix it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you managed to find the solution?